# Get value to show inside current xml node

Tags: sql, sql-server, xml, t-sql

So here is the issue I'm having and I hope this makes sense. I wrote a sql script to export data from tables into one xml file using **for xml path**.

Here is an example (You should be able to just copy, paste and run the below script):

```
    create table #temptable(
    mykey nvarchar(200),
    myarea nvarchar(200),
    mytype nvarchar(200),
    myvalue nvarchar(max)
    )

    insert into #temptable values ('6385465665245', 'area1', 'type1', 'This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.')
    insert into #temptable values ('6632525685488', 'area2', 'type2', 'This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.')

    select
    tmp.mykey as '@key',
    tmp.myarea as '@area',
    tmp.mytype as '@type',
    tmp.myvalue as 'value'

    from
    #temptable tmp

    for xml path('keyareatypes'), type

    IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
        DROP TABLE #temptable
```

if I run the above query, I get the following:

```
<keyareatypes key="6385465665245" area="area1" type="type1">
    <value>This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.</value>
</keyareatypes>
<keyareatypes key="6632525685488" area="area2" type="type2">
    <value>This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.</value>
</keyareatypes>
```

As you can see, in the `<keyareatypes>` node is another node called `<value>`. I do not want the `<value>` node there.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this gives the correct answer:

```
create table #temptable(
mykey nvarchar(200),
myarea nvarchar(200),
mytype nvarchar(200),
myvalue nvarchar(max)
)

insert into #temptable values ('6385465665245', 'area1', 'type1', 'This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.')
insert into #temptable values ('6632525685488', 'area2', 'type2', 'This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.')

select
mykey as 'keyareatypes/@key',
myarea as 'keyareatypes/@area',
mytype as 'keyareatypes/@type',
myvalue as keyareatypes
from
#temptable as keyareatypes
for xml path(''),TYPE

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temptable') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temptable
```

This returns

```
<keyareatypes key="6385465665245" area="area1" type="type1">
  This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.
</keyareatypes>
<keyareatypes key="6632525685488" area="area2" type="type2">
  This area should be inside the keyareatypes node and NOT in the value node.
</keyareatypes>
```